# Properly Requesting Publish Permissions using Facebook-Android SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, publish, facebook-android-sdk

Im working on a setting where users can choose to have their posts on my app published on facebook automatically.

I found this example:https://github.com/fbsamples/android-3.0-howtos/blob/master/PublishFeedHowTo/src/com/facebook/samples/publishfeedhowto/MainFragment.java

but, being this feature is a setting in my app i need to separate out the "allowing the permission" logic from the actual " making a publish request" which happens on another separate activity.

At first glance I assumed I could cut and paste the chunk of code below into my activity and it would work assuming my user had already logged in with facebook, but apparently I also have to implements uihelpers and  Session.StatusCallback's . What extra code (other than the logic below )do I NEED to implement in my settings activity that requests the permissions?

```
    private void publishStory() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {

            // Check for publish permissions    
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                    pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                            .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                    return;
               }

        }
    }

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to use the uiHelpers, I think all you should need in your code is to add a Session.Callback to your newPermissionsRequest to do the actual post when it gets called (of course, do another isSubsetOf check in your callback as the user could have denied your request). Also don't forget to override the onActivityResult method in your calling activity/fragment.

Answer (score 2):

As Ming Li has pointed out in a comment, you do not need to implement `uihelpers` but you'll need the following in addition.

Implement `StatusCallback`

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            switch (state) {
                case OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED:
                    publishStory(); // Comes here after the  new permissions are requested
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implement `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Add code to do the real work in `publishStory()`

```
private void publishStory() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {

        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
           }

        // Do the real work here
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we also have to add this line: newPermissionsRequest.setCallback(statusCallback);